# Здравствуйте, я не знаю названия этого приёма, поэтому не смог найти информации

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать так, что бы при открытии сайта на весь экран открывалось окно(с логотипом, к примеру) и при нажатии на любое место на этом окне, оно уезжало вверх , и пользователь продолжал бы работу с сайтом.)

Comment: Overlay, если хотите, делайте

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я искал